# labelled array python

Tags: python

I'm using the labelled array (larry) module (http://berkeleyanalytics.com/la/) to create a massive matrix where the rows (var names) and columns (dates) are labelled for easy access.

My problem is that I'm trying to divide a larry, but it keeps erroring out:

```
larry.set([''.join([country_and_channel,'EmailConfirmed#']),row['mm']],larry.get([''.join([country_and_channel,'EmailConfirmed#']),row['mm']]) / int(row['sume']))
```

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

however, all of the other operators (+,-,*) work

Comment: Could you make this reproducible? Provide a way of initialising the array with some dummy data so it's possible to copy/paste your code and have it break on someone else's computer. Surely the problem will manifest with a less massive dataset than you actually use.

Comment: invalid value encountered in double_scalars == divide by zero error - thx..